# Proving modular statements with variable exponents

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm currently stuck on proving congruence of mod statements with variable exponents.

First problem is showing $2^{mn} \equiv 1 \mod (2^n + 1)$ for all even m.

What I have done so far is:

- There exists an $x$ such that $m = 2x$ for the parity definition.
- $2^{mn} = 2^{2xn} = 4^{xn}$

I am now lost on how to manipulate that to become $2^{mn} - 1 = (2^n + 1)z$ where $z$ is an integer.

Second problem is showing that $a^m \% p \equiv a^{m \% (p-1)} \% p$ where p is a prime number using Fermat's Little Theorem. I know FLT means $a^{p-1} \%p = 1$ but I don't really know how to deal with the $m \% (p-1)$ exponent.

Any helps and hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
$$2^{mn}=(2^n)^m\equiv(-1)^m\equiv1\pmod{2^n+1}\ .$$
Second: if $k\%(p-1)=r$ then $k=m(p-1)+r$ for some $m$, and then
$$a^k\%p=(a^{p-1})^ma^r\%p=1^ma^r\%p=a^r\%p=a^{k\%(p-1)}\%p\ .$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I understand the second problem now but can you expand more on the first one? How did $2^n$ become $(-1)$ and how was the constraint "for all even m" used?

Comment: $2^n\equiv-1\pmod{2^n+1}$ and $(-1)^2=1$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part: $$2^n \equiv -1 \pmod{2^n +1}$$ and so $$(2^n)^m \equiv (-1)^m \pmod{2^n +1}.$$

Since $m$ is even, it follows that $$2^{mn} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n +1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would just like to clarify where $2^n \equiv -1 \pmod{2^n +1}$ came from? I understand what happens after that but I'm lost on how that was derived.

Comment: By definition $a \equiv b \pmod{m} \iff a-b=km$ for some integer $k$. Thus, if you plug $a=2^n, b=(-1)$, and $m=2^n +1$ into this definition, the result follows (with $k=1$). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, alright! I've been trying to derive it from the given. Thank you so much!